How to Interface a 4.3" TFT LCD (PCB4301MS V1.1) with ESP32 using TFT_eSPI Library?"
I'm trying to interface a 4.3" TFT LCD module (PCB4301MS V1.1) with an ESP32 using the TFT_eSPI library. I've connected the pins according to the TFT_eSPI User_Setup file, but the display isn't showing anything. I've tried using both 8-bit parallel and SPI modes, but neither seems to work. I'm unsure if the issue is related to the wiring, the library configuration, or the driver used by the display. I've searched online for the exact driver and compatible library but haven't found a solution that works. Any guidance on how to correctly set up this display with the ESP32 would be greatly appreciated.
I connected the TFT module to my ESP32 using both SPI and 8-bit parallel connections, and configured the TFT_eSPI library by selecting the HX8357 driver in the User_Setup.h file. I expected the screen to initialize and display the test graphics from the library’s example code. However, the display remains blank, and I'm not seeing any output. I also tried different pin configurations and even adjusted the SPI frequency, but none of these changes resolved the issue.
